# Is there any possibility to compile something for CentOS from the c# solution?

Tags: c#, compilation, centos, solution

I know that it sounds stupid, but I have some c# solutions build into some exe files. I would want to use those solutions on Linux but I cannot use the exe files there. Is there any possibility to compile something for linux from the c# solution?

Comment: Why can't you use those exe's there? You did install mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Mono on CentOS:
http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx

Recompile your EXE using MonoDevelop/Mono
http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: I'm doing that now. So far I've installed Mono but something went wrong because when I type momo --version : bash: mono: command not found